# Экранирование кавычек в MySQL (Laravel Seeder)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Добрый вечер!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, с помощью DB Seeder пытаюсь внести значение в поле типа json:

```
'rating' => '{"avg":2,"clean":2,"place":1,"keeper":1}'
```

Однако в MySQL кавычки экранируются, и получается так:

```
"{\"avg\":2,\"clean\":2,\"place\":1,\"keeper\":1}"
```

При создании json-массивов такой проблемы нет:

```
[{"number":"+7 999 9999999","name":"Имя"},{"number":"8 111 1234567","name":"Кое-кто"}]
```

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

**Update**: добавил код Seeder'a
class ObjectTableSeeder extends Seeder {

```
public function run()
{
    \App\Object::create([
        'category_id' => '2',
        'owner_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Some name"',
        'rating' => '{"avg":2,"clean":2,"place":1,"keeper":1}',
        'phones' => '[{"number":"+7 999 9999999","name":"Some name"},{"number":"8 111 1234567","name":"Body"}]',
        'status' => '1'
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: Возможно ваш способ вывода строки сбивает вас с толку. На самом деле данные хранятся без проблем.

Comment: К сожалению, это не так. Получить данные json-объекта получается только после ручного удаления обратных слешей

Comment: Может покажете код?

Comment: Ваша строка выглядит нормально. В том смысле, что если я буквально напишу `$s = здесь ваша строка с экранированными кавычками`, то получу *правильный* результат, который отлично преобразуется через json_decode()

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт. Проблема была в том, что поле $rating имело автоматическую сериализацию и десериализацию при внесении/получении данных и БД.Соответственно

Comment: Заменил при добавлении JSON на массив и все стало отлично.